# Quadratic residue classes

Tags: congruences, quadratic-residues

By considering 4x^2 + 3 show that there are infinitely many primes in the residue class 1 mod 6.

Not too sure how to start this but is it along the lines of 4x^2 +3 ≡ 1 mod 6?

Comment: It meant to look at $p$ a prime divisor of $N = 4n^2+3$ and use quadratic reciprocity to deduce a condition for $p \equiv 1 \bmod 6$. Next set $n = \prod_{i \le j} p_i$ to obtain $p$ is a new prime in $1 \bmod 6$.